# c# programmable selecting dropdown value

Tags: c#, dropdownbox

I am new at C# and it seems the following code below does not seem to select my combobox value:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   cbPortNumber.SelectedValue = 3;
```

or

```
   cbPortNumber.setValue("3");
```

or

```
   cbPortNumber.SelectedIndex = cbPortNumber.FindString("3");
```

or

```
   cbPortNumber.SelectedIndex = cbPortNumber.Items.IndexOf(cbPortNumber.Items.FindByValue("HDMI 4"));

}
```

The dropdown looks like this:
[image]

All code above does not seem to select HDMI 4 on the list... I dont have any errors but i also don't have it being selected.

Any help would be great!

**update showing combobox**
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

```
    // 
    // cbPortNumber
    // 
    this.cbPortNumber.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Append;
    this.cbPortNumber.Enabled = false;
    this.cbPortNumber.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.cbPortNumber.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(174, 40);
    this.cbPortNumber.Name = "cbPortNumber";
    this.cbPortNumber.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(133, 21);
    this.cbPortNumber.TabIndex = 11;
    this.cbPortNumber.Text = "global_hdmi_port";
    this.helpPortNumber.SetToolTip(this.cbPortNumber, "The HDMI port number, to which you connected your USB-CEC adapter.");
    this.cbPortNumber.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cbPortNumber_SelectedIndexChanged);

#region Global settings
public CECSettingByte HDMIPort
{
  get
  {
    if (!_settings.ContainsKey(KeyHDMIPort))
    {
      CECSettingByte setting = new CECSettingByte(KeyHDMIPort, "HDMI port", 1, _changedHandler) { LowerLimit = 1, UpperLimit = 15, EnableSetting = EnableHDMIPortSetting };
      setting.Format += delegate(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs args)
      {
        ushort tmp;
        if (ushort.TryParse((string)args.Value, out tmp))
          args.Value = "HDMI " + args.Value;
      };

      Load(setting);
      _settings[KeyHDMIPort] = setting;
    }
    return _settings[KeyHDMIPort].AsSettingByte;
  }
}
```

**Update 3**

And this is what fires the action after selecting something in that dropdown:

```
private void OnSettingChanged(CECSetting setting, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
  if (setting.KeyName == CECSettings.KeyHDMIPort)
  {
    CECSettingByte byteSetting = setting as CECSettingByte;
    if (byteSetting != null)
    {
      if (!Settings.OverridePhysicalAddress.Value)
        Config.HDMIPort = byteSetting.Value;
      CECActions.SetConnectedDevice(Settings.ConnectedDevice.Value, byteSetting.Value);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So this code is working fine for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

you can not access a ItemSource if there are no items to access. The simple way is to Init the items over the Desinger

[image]

( Sory for the nonlocalized IDE ) than you can set the Property SelectedIndex to a Index that exits. The other way is to Add all HDMI items with the `Combobox1.Items.Add` function.

If you ever used Forms in VB ... its still the same

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var hdmi = "HDMI";

    for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add( hdmi + i);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Items.Count >= 2)
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

Comment: Adding breakpoints at the start of the event handlers will show you if/when they're being triggered.

Comment: Using your code i get this: **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)**

Comment: be sure that you jusing the right combobox! set a breakpoint to the assignment and look whats inside the ItemSouce

Comment: I am using the correct combobox. See updated OP for an image.

Comment: How do you fill your ItemSource?

Comment: Trying to figure that out myself. Its not a program i wrote. I've done a search in code for **cbPortNumber** but i dont get any code that seems to add those *HDMI x* values.... Again, im new at C#.. I'm a VB guy :o)

Comment: I justed updated my OP again with the design of the cbPortNumber if that helps

Comment: Even the **cbPortNumber_SelectedIndexChanged** in the code is blank so i dont even know what its doing after a value is selected?

Comment: well than its clear ... you can not access a ItemSource if there are no items to access. The simple way is to Init the items over the [Desinger](http://www7.pic-upload.de/11.05.13/szq6t9dm5to2.jpg) ( Sory for the nonlocalized IDE ) than you can set the Property SelectedIndex to a Index that exits. The other way is to Add all HDMI items with the `Combobox1.Items.Add` function

If you used VB Forms ... its still the same

Comment: When the program loads (starts up) it already has the dropdown populated as shown in my image in my OP...I'm just using a button in order to select a value in that dropbox.

Comment: Found where it was populating the HDMI x. Updated my OP.

Comment: The value for item count is 0